# VB.NET Read all entries of XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

Trying to read the following XML file in VB.net

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TrustedDomains>
  <Domain>one.co.uk</Domain>
  <Domain>two.co.uk</Domain>
</TrustedDomains>
```

My issue is it will only read one line and then moves on. My code is as follows.

```
        Dim XML As XDocument = XDocument.Load(XMLFile)
        For Each domainElement As XElement In XML.<TrustedDomains>
            Dim domain As String = domainElement.<Domain>.Value
            ListBox1.Items.Add(domain)
        Next
```

I have tried both `XElement` and `XContainer`. I can find many examples of reading an XML with multiple values, but nothing for a simple list.

Comment: Well, you do have one `<TrustedDomains>` element, so there's only one to `for each` through. You probably wanted for each `In XML.<TrustedDomains>.<Domain>`, or even `Items.AddRange(XML.<TrustedDomains>.<Domain>.Select(Function(d) d.Value).ToArray())`.

Comment: I have updated to the following and its working as expected, I will attempt your suggestion of adding a range as i would imagine its quicker fo larger XML files ? `For Each domainElement As XElement In XML.<TrustedDomains>.<Domain>

                Dim domain As String = domainElement.Value
                ListBox1.Items.Add(domain)

            Next`

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be using XML a lot I'd get acquainted with [XElement and LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/xelement-class-overview).

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    xe = XElement.Load(XMLFile)

    'this
    For Each domainElement As XElement In xe...<Domain>
        ListBox1.Items.Add(domainElement.Value)
    Next

    'or this
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange((From el In xe...<Domain>
                                Select el.Value).ToArray)
```

Comment: `xe...<Domain>` is a broader set than `xe.<TrustedDomains>.<Domain>`, and I don't see how `el` could be `Nothing` there.

Comment: @GSerg - It is not given the example XML.  You are correct about the Where clause, I'll edit the post.  Thx